Upload multiple photos for a product in the store
I am loading a store site with Django.
I need to upload 4 photos for one product But I can only upload one photo
can you help me?
my models in products:
class Product(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    Descriptions = models.TextField()
    Price = models.IntegerField()
    Image = models.ImageField(upload_to='product')
    category = models.ManyToManyField(Category, null=True, blank=True)
    Discount = models.SmallIntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    Size = models.ManyToManyField(ProductSize, related_name='product')
    Color = models.ManyToManyField(ProductColor, related_name='product', blank=True)
    Property = models.ManyToManyField(ProductProperty, related_name='product')

My Views in products:
class ProductDetail(DetailView):
    template_name = 'product/single-product.html'
    model = Product


Option - 1: Use ForeignKey to upload multiple images
class Images(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Product, default=None)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_image_filename,
                              verbose_name='Image')

Option - 2: without image field
This is the preferred way - I have applied this in my project
1. Add image at a specific location (at filesystem or AWS S3)
2. Like: prod_images/product_id/image1.jpg, prod_images/product_id/image2.jpg ...
3. In your views you can respond back with above images links


